# How to make INNER JOIN ON different fields by condition

Tags: sql, oracle, case, inner-join

I need to make `inner join` by different conditions depending on the `doc_type` field value.

This is schema

```
Person (
  ...
  doc_type VARCHAR2(40),
  doc_series VARCHAR2(4),
  doc_number VARCHAR2(6),
  doc_date DATE
)

Document (
  id INTEGER,
  type VARCHAR2(40),
  series VARCHAR2(4),
  number VARCHAR2(6),
  date DATE
)
```

For example, if `doc_type` value is `01` I need to make join by `doc_type` and `doc_series` columns and if `doc_type` value is `02` then join should be done by `doc_type`, `doc_series`, `doc_number` and `doc_date`.

Something like this

```
SELECT d.* FROM document d
INNER JOIN person p ON
(CASE when d.doc_type = '01' then
  p.doc_type = d.type AND
  p.doc_series = d.series
      when d.doc_type = '02' then
  p.doc_type = d.type AND
  p.doc_series = d.series AND 
  p.doc_number = d.doc_number AND
  p.doc_date = d.doc_date
);
```

How can I do it in Oracle DB?

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in WHERE and ON clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM document d
INNER JOIN person p ON p.doc_series = d.series AND
( d.doc_type = '01' AND p.doc_type = d.type) OR
( d.doc_type = '02' AND p.doc_type = d.type AND p.doc_number = d.doc_number AND
  p.doc_date = d.doc_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.* FROM document d
INNER JOIN person p ON (
(d.doc_type = '01' AND p.doc_type = d.type AND p.doc_series = d.series)
OR
( d.doc_type = '02' AND p.doc_type = d.type AND p.doc_series = d.series AND 
  p.doc_number = d.doc_number AND
  p.doc_date = d.doc_date)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use union with to join tables that match the condition:

```
   SELECT d.* FROM document d
INNER JOIN person p ON
  p.doc_type = d.type AND
  p.doc_series = d.series
where d.doc_typ = '01'
UNION ALL
SELECT d.* 
FROM document d
INNER JOIN person p ON
  p.doc_type = d.type AND
  p.doc_series = d.series AND 
  p.doc_number = d.doc_number AND
  p.doc_date = d.doc_date
where d.doc_typ = '02'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really are looking for CASE, try this:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM document d
INNER JOIN person p ON 
  (CASE when (p.doc_type = d.type AND
            p.doc_series = d.series) then
            '01'
      when ( p.doc_type = d.type AND
             p.doc_series = d.series AND 
             p.doc_number = d.doc_number AND
             p.doc_date = d.doc_date) then
             '02'
    end ) = p.doc_type;
```

As you have not properly mentioned the column names in the tables, i made use of the query you have given. Please check the columns and run it. Hope it helps.